# Как сохранить адрес откуда перенаправился в PHP переменной?

Tags: .htaccess, php

Как сделать, чтобы сохранить адрес, с которого я перенаправился с помощью .htaccess, в PHP переменной?

Как сделать проверку? Допустим я ввел в адресной строке /123.php. Как запустить проверку на наличие данной записи в БД? В какой файл приписать данную проверку?

Я сделал перенаправление через htaccess на файл redirect.php. В котором я проверяю на соответствие в БД. Но как мне узнать какой адрес был записан до перенаправления?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] и думаю, тогда вы узнаете прошлую страницу.